# Error when training support vector machine (SVM) classifier

Tags: machine-learning

I am running `Classify` function using a support vector machine model. I get an error that I can not fix.

Here is my code. The data is imported from a file *.txt:

```
files = FileNames["*.txt"];
data = N@Flatten[ReadList[#]] & /@ files;
Dimensions@data (*500*3000*)
trainset = Association[{"class1" -> data[[1 ;; 50]], "class2" -> data[[51 ;; 100]]}]
validset = Association[{"class1" -> data[[101 ;; 120]],  "class2" -> data[[101 ;; 120]]}]
Classify[trainset, ValidationSet -> validset, Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"].
```

Here is a link to the directory which contains all files. [files](http://www.filedropper.com/files_13)

And here are the errors:

> Dot::dotsh: Tensors <<>>,{1.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,<<791>>},<<48>>,<<50>>} and {<<>>,<<784>>} have incompatible shapes. >>
>
> LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM::blrank: The argument MachineLearning`General`PackagePrivate`dist$182968 evaluates to rank 1. Rank 2 is expected.
>
> Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of <<>> cannot be transposed. >>
>
> Commonest::arg1: The first argument is expected to be a list. >>
>
> LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM::blrank: The argument MachineLearning`General`PackagePrivate`dist$185704 evaluates to rank 1. Rank 2 is expected.

When I delete the `validationSet` option, or I use, for example, the `LogisticRegression` the training finishes correctly!

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8c28219930400bd3a921afba45a6cf31871254195afed17e0ce9d2c62fda488b/analysis/1455255328/

Comment: I've reported similar bug in August. In my case I had kernel crash. Problem also was in ValidationSet.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev  What version do you use? I am running Mathematica 10.1.0

Comment: @Developer2000 10.3.1

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev, I receive the confirmation of technical support about this bug.